# Avoid repeated records

Tags: mysql, triggers

Well I'm trying to filter repeated records on a table called "productos" with a trigger on this way

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_prouctos_repetidos
AFTER INSERT
    ON productos FOR EACH ROW

  SELECT marca_producto
  FROM productos
  WHERE marca_producto LIKE 

END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

But i neeed to know how to get the "`marca_producto`" field's value before insert to the table
Is my query correct?
How can I complete the like clause?

Comment: use a UNIQUE constraint on the relevant columns , so that no double name or what ever you need uinique. Your trigger must be a BEFORE INSERT and accessing the new data get  like this NEW.marca_producto

Comment: If you wont to prevent duplicates in table you should to use `UNIQUE INDEX`.  https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/